# Java, Linux: how to detect whether two java.io.Files refer to the same physical file

Tags: java, file, unix, equals

I'm looking for an efficient way to detect whether two `java.io.File`s refer to the same physical file. According to the docs, `File.equals()` **should** do the job:

> Tests this abstract pathname for
>   equality with the given object.
>   Returns true if and only if the
>   argument is not null and is an
>   abstract pathname that denotes the
>   same file or directory as this
>   abstract pathname.

However, given a FAT32 partition (actually a TrueCrypt container) which is mounted at /media/truecrypt1:

```
new File("/media/truecrypt1/File").equals(new File("/media/truecrypt1/file")) == false
```

Would you say that this conforms to the specification? And in this case, how to work around that problem?

**Update:** Thanks to commenters, for Java 7 I've found `java.io.Files.isSameFile()` which works for me.

Comment: I'm not sure (that's why I post it as a comment), but maybe [`getCanonicalFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalFile()) helps.

Comment: On Unix, these files are not the same. ;)

Comment: @Peter: not in general, but if `/media/truecrypt1` is a FAT filesystem, then they will (given the default mount options) refer to the exact same content.

Comment: @Joachim: unfortunately, no: `new File("/media/truecrypt1/File").getCanonicalFile().equals(new File("/media/truecrypt1/file").getCanonicalFile()) == false`

Comment: @Joachim: But equals only compare path name. It will return true even if the files don't exist, as long as the path is the same (case sensitive for Unix).

Comment: Java 7 allows you to get the FileStore.type() which you might be able to use to determine whether a directory or file is case insensitive.  The problem you have is that "/Media/truecrypt1/File" and "/media/truecrypt1/File" are not the same, unless you have a symbolic link. ;)

Comment: @Dikei: yes, I know. That's the way that `File` is specified and it makes a lot of sense in the unix world (usually). **But** the problem remains that deleting `/media/truecrypt1/File` will make `/media/truecrypt1/file` go away (given the preconditions above) and there's no obvious way to check that in Java.

Comment: @Peter Good pointer, `java.io.Files.isSameFile()` -- which is present in Java 7 -- works for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer in @Joachim's comment is normally correct.  The way to determine if two `File` object refer to the same OS file is to use getCanonicalFile() or getCanonicalPath().  The javadoc says this:

> *"A canonical pathname is both absolute and unique. [...]  Every pathname that denotes an existing file or directory has a unique canonical form."*

So the following *should* work:

```
File f1 = new File("/media/truecrypt1/File");  // different capitalization ...
File f2 = new File("/media/truecrypt1/file");  // ... but same OS file (on Windows)
if (f1.getCanonicalPath().equals(f2.getCanonicalPath())) {
    System.out.println("Files are equal ... no kittens need to die.");
}
```

---

However, it would appear that you are viewing a FAT32 file system mounted on UNIX / Linux.  AFAIK, Java does not know that this is happening, and is just applying the generic UNIX / Linux rules for file names ... which give the wrong answer in this scenario.

If this is what is really happening, I don't think there is a reliable solution in pure Java 6.  However,

- You could do some hairy JNI stuff; e.g. get the file descriptor numbers and then in native code, use the [`fstat(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) system call to get hold of the two files' device and inode numbers and comparing those.
- Java 7 `java.nio.file.Path.equals(Object)` looks like it *might* give the right answer if you call `resolve()` on the paths first to resolve symlinks.  (It is a little unclear from the javadoc whether each mounted filesystem on Linux will correspond to a distinct `FileSystem` object.)
- The Java 7 tutorials have [this section](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/check.html#same) on seeing if two `Path` objects are for the same file ... which recommends using `java.nio.file.Files.isSameFile(Path, Path)`

---

> Would you say that this conforms to the specification?

No and yes.

- No in the sense that the `getCanonicalPath()` method is not returning the same value for each existing OS file ... which is what you'd expect from reading the javadoc.
- Yes in the technical sense that the Java codebase (not the javadoc) is the ultimate specification ... both in theory and in practice.

Comment: I disagree with the very last item: If I took this statement literaly, then there *can be no bug* in Java, as every bug would be part of the specification. That has been proven to be wrong in the past ;-)

Comment: But the point is ... even if it is a bug, Sun/Oracle will often say "won't fix" ... and not correct the javadoc either.  IIRC, when TCK testing the rule for conformance is to do what the Sun JRE does ... not what the javadoc says.  In effect, the library code is the gold standard for conformance, not any documentation.  That makes it the ultimate specification for anyone trying to reimplement the class libraries ... as GNU Classpath and Apache Harmony have done.

Comment: the attitude that a reference impl is the correct impl, when in fact a documented spec exists (that contradicts the reference impl), is imho a very wrong attitude to take. It may be a practical attitude to take, but the health of a spec is only as good as the ease with which to conform to the spec by the various parties involved.

Comment: @Chii - unfortunately, that attitude is the way it is.  I suppose you could send an email to Larry Ellison telling him what he needs to do to fix the problem ... but I don't think it would make any difference.  Or you could invoke Adam Savage's mantra - "I reject your reality and substitute my own."

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work on Android. exists() returns true for both paths, while getCanonicalPath() returns two different paths.

Comment: @LearnOpenGLES - that's not conclusive evidence of anything.  What are the paths in question?

Answer (score 3):

you could try to obtain an [exclusive write lock on the file](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#tryLock%28long,%20long,%20boolean%29), and see if that fails:

```
boolean isSame;
try {
   FileOutputStream file1 = new FileOutputStream (file1);
   FileOutputStream file2 = new FileOutputStream (file2);
   FileChannel channel1 = file1.getChannel();
   FileChannel channel2 = file2.getChannel();
   FileLock fileLock1 = channel1.tryLock();
   FileLock fileLock2 = channel2.tryLock();
   isSame = fileLock2 != null;
} catch(/*appropriate exceptions*/) {
   isSame = false;
} finally {
   fileLock1.unlock();
   fileLock2.unlock();
   file1.close();
   file2.close();
   ///cleanup etc...
}
System.out.println(file1 + " and " + file2 + " are " + (isSame?"":"not") + " the same");
```

This is not always guaranteed to be correct tho - because another process could potentially have obtained the lock, and thus fail for you. But at least this doesn't require you to shell out to an external process.

Comment: Thank you! that helped me immensely, as symbolic links were not eradicated in linux for some reason using canonical paths :(

Comment: you have to be slightly careful using this mechanism - it uses the system's native file locks, and so your program's behaviour might be slightly different depending on OS and file system type (e.g., if you used it a NFS mount, it might not work as intended since NFS doesn't have real locks iirc).

Answer (score 2):

There's a chance the same file has two paths (e.g. over the network `\\localhost\file` and `\\127.0.0.1\file` would refer to the same file with a different path).
I would go with comparing digests of both files to determine whether they are identical or not. Something like this

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        File f1 = new File("\\\\79.129.94.116\\share\\bots\\triplon_bots.jar");
        File f2 = new File("\\\\triplon\\share\\bots\\triplon_bots.jar");
        System.out.println(f1.getCanonicalPath().equals(f2.getCanonicalPath()));
        System.out.println(computeDigestOfFile(f1).equals(computeDigestOfFile(f2)));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String computeDigestOfFile(File f) throws Exception {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
    try {
        is = new DigestInputStream(is, md);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while(is.read(buffer) != -1) {
            md.update(buffer);
        }
    }
    finally {
        is.close();
    }
    return new BigInteger(1,md.digest()).toString(16);
}
```

It outputs

```
false
true
```

This approach is of course much slower than any sort of path comparison, it also depends on the size of files. Another possible side effect is that two files will be considered equals equal indifferently from their locations.

Comment: Every time I see all those backslashes I want to recommend that some ancient designer get their head examined. Choosing the escape character as a path delimiter was one of the stupider things Microsoft ever did, and billions of people are forevermore paying the price of that folly. Using proper slashes the way they were meant to be used instead of confusing backslashes would save everyone a great deal of misery.

Comment: computing digest to check if they are the same file is not correct because they could be a file that is a copy of the other - thus not the same "physically"

Comment: If you hate MS so much for it, you should then see some code for JSP injection to generate Javascript and match some regexes (here's a snippet: loopCall += (loopCall.equals("")? "" : ", ") + "{\\\\'bibtex\\\\':\\\\'" + bibtexLink + "\\\\', " + "\\\\'cited\\\\':" + "\\\\'" + URLEncoder.encode(citedLink, util.getSessionCharset()) + "\\\\', \\\\'placeholder\\\\':\\\\'" + placeholder + "\\\\'}";). So maybe it was the escape character that was wrong...

Comment: @Chii you apparently are rephrasing what I'm saying at the end of my post. So to say "is not correct" is not correct itself, as it assumes some business logic, that e.g. two files are identical only if they have the same name or same location, at the same not taking into account any other.

Comment: Why it the world would you ever use something that required such nonsense? Programming language conventions of what a backslash is for substantially antedate Microsoft. They did this to make it intentionally difficult, for which act there is neither excuse nor mercy.

Comment: @tchrist: they actually used the backslash as a path separator because they had already used the slash for CP/M-style command line switches.

Comment: @ninjalj: Yes, I do recall CP/M. But that’s a horrible excuse. They should have fixed their shell. Their kernel, they did fix. The incredible amount of suffering they have inflicted upon billions is so huge that you’d think the *Bill&Melinda Gates Foundation* should take up the cause.  Oh, the humanity!

Answer (score 2):

The Files.isSameFile method was added for exactly this kind of usage - that is, you want to check if two non-equal paths locate the same file.

Comment: Sadly not every developer (still, in 2013) has luxury to use Java 1.7 and abandon support for 1.6 and previous versions of Java.

Comment: how do you do this for a directory, this throws an exception if the "File" is a directory and none of the Paths work. canonical may have a `~` in it in one case and not in another case but both locations are the same physical directories. Shouldn't this be a common thing to need?

Answer (score 1):

On *nix systems, casing *does* have an importance. `file` is not the same as `File` or `fiLe`.

Comment: I'm on a FAT32 partition, here `FILE` and `file` are the same.

Comment: well if the OS considers case, I'm guessing there is no way for Java to know they are similar, regardless of the file system.

Answer (score 1):

The API doc of `equals()` says (right after your quote):

> On UNIX systems, alphabetic case is
>   significant in comparing pathnames; on
>   Microsoft Windows systems it is not.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Runtime.exec() of

```
ls -i /fullpath/File # extract the inode number.
df /fullpath/File # extract the "Mounted on" field.
```

If the mount point and the "inode" number is the same, they are the same file whether you have symbolic links or case-insensitive file systems.

Or even

```
bash test "file1" -ef "file2"
```

> FILE1 and FILE2 have the same device and inode numbers

Comment: I see we think along the same lines. :)

Answer (score 1):

The traditional Unix way to test whether two filenames refer to the same underlying filesystem object is to `stat` them and test whether they have the same `[dev,ino]` pair.

That does assume no redundant mounts, however. If those are allowed, you have to go about it differently.